# VS Code Error: while attempting to install Azure Functions extension

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am able to install other non-azure extension. This error only persists for Azure extensions. I have tried reinstalling VS Code. Tried to install it by running VS code as Admin. Installing VS code in some other location and also "--no-certificate-error" mode.

Error Log in VS code output window:

```
2023-02-28 16:33:51.354 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-02-28 16:33:52.586 [error] [sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate]: Unknown language in `contributes.html5-boilerplate.language`. Provided value: njk
2023-02-28 16:33:52.587 [error] [sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate]: Unknown language in `contributes.html5-boilerplate.language`. Provided value: django-html
2023-02-28 16:33:52.587 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: vue
2023-02-28 16:33:54.942 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 98ms
2023-02-28 16:34:07.062 [error] [sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate]: Unknown language in `contributes.html5-boilerplate.language`. Provided value: njk
2023-02-28 16:34:07.063 [error] [sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate]: Unknown language in `contributes.html5-boilerplate.language`. Provided value: django-html
2023-02-28 16:34:07.063 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: vue
2023-02-28 16:34:12.858 [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery {"name":"Canceled"}
2023-02-28 16:34:40.688 [error] Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:34:40.714 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:35:10.648 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:35:24.873 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:37:51.054 [error] Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:37:51.134 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:38:04.185 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:38:11.243 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:38:16.763 [error] Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
2023-02-28 16:38:16.825 [error] UnhandledException: Signature: UnhandledException
    at yt.download (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:62:17985)
    at async $.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:90:171351)
```

Answer (score 0):

***As per the error I could observe, there is no issues with the Azure functions or any extensions in the visual studio marketplace.***

Check your internet connection because improper network connection is interrupting it to install the extension.

Check any `firewalls` are blocking it and if any are present, disable the firewall and try installing the extension again.

If you are working with any `vpn`, try installation by disconnecting it temporarily for some time.

*I've verified the same in my* `VScode` *environment and it's running as expected:*

Goto `Visual Studio Code marketplace` and search for `Azure functions` extensions.

**Note**: If still the issue persists, reload the `visual studio code` and install it once again.

[image]

Comment: I have tried all the things that you have mentioned, except disabling the firewall, which I cannot do on my office system ,I'll bug the IT support guys, who are not willing to accept that this is because of a network issue, anyway thanks.

Comment: Can you upgrade the `pip` version and try upgrading the `VScode` version. @dk_1999